# Swift: set locale character type for Process()

Tags: swift, terminal

I am trying to make a Swift Playground run a command in Mac Terminal and have it return the output (what's printed in Terminal). I have this function which works fine on most commands:

```
func runCommand(path: String, args: [String]) -> (data: String, error: String) {
    // create task instance
    let task = Process()

    // set the task parameters
    task.launchPath = path
    task.arguments = args

    // create pipes and make the task put all the output there
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errorPipe

    // launch task
    task.launch()

    // get data
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let dataOutput = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
    let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let errorOutput = NSString(data: errorData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    return (dataOutput, errorOutput)
}
```

The problem I am having is with a Python 3 command that uses Click. Whenever I try to run this command using `runCommand()`, it returns an error saying it has a problem with the fact that Python was configured to use `ASCII` instead of `UTF-8` as encoding for the environment.
This same problem occurs when running the command in Terminal when its locale category character type is set to `ASCII` like this:

```
$ export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"
```

However, it can be fixed by setting it to `UTF-8` like this:

```
$ export LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
```

The question is, how can I achieve the same thing (set the `LC_CTYPE` to `UTF-8`) in Swift?

EDIT:
This question was marked as a duplicate of a question that deals with the functionality of dictionaries whereas this question is about setting locales / character types and is therefore different. If the answer to this question is in fact in the other one's answer, I would like to ask for further explanation.

Comment: `export LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` *is* about setting environment variables. You only have to modify the given answer according to your needs: `environment["LC_CTYPE"] = "UTF-8"`

Comment: Thank you! That worked as I wanted it to.